# Bootstrap 3 Full width and height layout with 3 Column Flex or Col

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a bit stuck with this simple page (I know you might roll eye with it, just bear with me). I have use Bootstrap for many years until something hit me as my manager would like to see it on mobile. I have tried with many different ways but none matched the layout of the next screenshot with a `Navbar` in the middle. Width is fine for me but I have a problem setting the height.

[image]

Also, on desktop I tried to use three columns layout and it looks fine, until I add a middle navbar (it looks bloat and horrible in background), and all the column are not using the correct height, so I suspect the CSS is a bit wrong. I have tried with `height:auto` or `height:fixed` but none of them are perfect as you can see on the clip of code I wrote.

[image]

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
</div>
```

I am using this for col but I'm sure that I will tell off that I should use flex.

I am using this background for images, I have look around for template or example but most of them are using one image for a full-width background. not much height with column

```
    .MainBackgroundImages {
        padding-bottom: 40%; 
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Here is a snippet I wrote as you can see the height is bit issue.

```css
.leftHalf {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/2000/FF0000/FFFFFF/?text=Left');
}

.centerHalf {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center
}

.rightHalf {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/2000/FFFF00/00000/?text=right');
}

.MainBackgroundImages {
  padding-bottom: 40%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div style="”clear: both;"></div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5 MainBackgroundImages leftHalf"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 centerHalf">
    <br>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" id="custom-bootstrap-menu" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ishka Sport</a> <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li>
              <a href="/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/products">kayak</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/about-us">Nipper Boards</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/contact">Accessories</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5 MainBackgroundImages rightHalf">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, just as an start point: on **SM** screen size and above you want 3 columns with configuration `(5, 2, 5)` all of they using the available height of the screen?

Comment: yes i have use SM but it still the same issue, as both (desktop and mobile ) are fix on the height of the screen as I keep getting a gap on the bottom as I know it not 100% height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a full height layout, you will need to tell the parent element of the `columns` to get all the available height of the viewport, this can be done defining the next class:

```
full-height {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

And assigning this class to the `row` that wraps the `columns`. After this, you need to set the `height` property of the three columns you have to `100%` (So they will use 100% height of the parent element).

Now, on small devices (**SM**), you want the previous layout to change: all the columns will use the 12 available grids of Bootstrap. So, you will have to manage the height of the columns with a media query like the next one (Bootstrap 3 breakpoints are documented here: [Bootstrap 3 Media Queries](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-media-queries)):

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

    .leftHalf {
        height: 40%;
    }

    .centerHalf {
        height: 20%;
    }

    .rightHalf {
        height: 40%;
    }
}
```

All of the previous explanation is used on the next working example, check it playing with the full screen mode and resizing the browser. It is a homework for you, to correct displaying the layout of the middle `navbar`. Hope this helps you as the base of the layout you need.

```css
.full-height {
  height: 100vh;
}

.leftHalf {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/2000/FF0000/FFFFFF/?text=Left');
  height: 100%;
}

.centerHalf {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.rightHalf {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/2000/FFFF00/00000/?text=right');
  height: 100%;
}

.MainBackgroundImages {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Custom style for Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

    .leftHalf {
        height: 40%;
    }

    .centerHalf {
        height: 20%;
    }

    .rightHalf {
        height: 40%;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row full-height">

  <div class="col-md-5 MainBackgroundImages leftHalf"></div>

  <div class="col-md-2 centerHalf">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" id="custom-bootstrap-menu" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ishka Sport</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/products">kayak</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about-us">Nipper Boards</a></li>
          <li><a href="/contact">Accessories</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-5 MainBackgroundImages rightHalf"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank, it does make sense! it more clear with full width and full height together. Thank you.